# How are CIFS and SMB related to each other?

Tags: server-message-block, cifs, network-protocols, protocols

Are they synonyms, or components of a protocol stack?
Answers with proof links are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're pretty much the same.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS), they are the same.

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365233%28VS.85%29.aspx), CIFS is a dialect of SMB.

Comment: Thanks. It appears CIFS is a specialisation of SMB, just like RDP is a narrow specialisation of GSS/MCS stack (T.120). Is it close?

Comment: [MS-SMB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246232(v=prot.10).aspx) puts them another way: SMB is an extention of CIFS... so where's the truth?

Comment: The truth is most likely [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-heizer-cifs-v1-spec-00) :) Which is that CIFS is "based on SMB".

Comment: Or even better, [here](http://ubiqx.org/cifs/rfc-draft/index.html) or [there](http://www.cifs.org)

Comment: seems that the path is SMB->CIFS->SMB1.0->... Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[CIFS is an implementation of SMB](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CIFS.html). For all [intents and purposes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS) they are the same thing.

Comment: from the first link it appears that SMB to CIFS is like SUN-RPC for NFS; while the second one puts them in a row. What do I miss?